# Android Webview - How to retain text data when orientation changes

Tags: android, webview, orientation, android-fragments

I want to retain the text data in the webview (i.e the data entered in the text box of the form in the url loaded) across the orientation changes.
I used, **onSaveInstanceState()** ***restoreState(savedInstanceState)** it restores previous state but not the values.

I resorted to use **webview with Fragments**, still no luck in retaining the data. Also when using Fragments the app crashes when orientation changes.

I cannot use **android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation** as I need keyboard when the orientation changes.

Can anyone provide a solution to this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` without the `keyboardHidden`?

**Edit**: You may also want to use `screenSize` when targeting API 13 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
**android:configChanges="orientation" without the keyboardHidden**
Was not helpful to me it restarted webview as usual, thats why I resorted to **onSaveInstanceState()** **restoreState(savedInstanceState)** This is slightly better because it restores the webview before orientation change, but does not retain the text values inside it.
So I resorted to Fragments with Webview, But Iam unsure how to implement it properly to solve my purpose.

Comment: Did you add screenSize? Everything will be restarted in API 13+ without declaring screenSize (along with orientation) in your configChanges.

Comment: I used android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" still the webview restarts unless I use keyboardHidden . Which I cannot compramise. Do you have idea of Fragments with webview to retain values ?